# "There's an error in your program: EOL while scanning single-quoted" python 2.5 need help to solve this code

Tags: python

```
menu = "What would you like:\n\
1. A complement?\n\ 
2. An insult?\n\ 
3. A proverb?\n\ 
4. An idiom?\n\ 
9. Quit\n" 
answer = int(raw_input(menu)) 
if answer == 1: 
    print "You look lovely today!" 
elif answer == 2: 
    print "You smell funny." 
elif answer == 3: 
    print "Two wrongs don't make a right. But three lefts do..." 
elif answer == 4: 
    print "The pen is mightier than the sword." 
elif answer == 9: 
    print "Goodbye!!!"
```

An error says "There's an error in your program: EOL while scanning single-quoted string"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To declare `menu` variable you need a multiline string:

```
menu = """What would you like:\n\
1. A complement?\n\ 
2. An insult?\n\ 
3. A proverb?\n\ 
4. An idiom?\n\ 
9. Quit\n"""
```

EDIT: Assuming you just want each menu entry on a new line, you can get rid of newline characters, so:

```
menu = """What would you like:
1. A complement? 
2. An insult?
3. A proverb?
4. An idiom?
9. Quit\n"""
```

Will print each entry as a new line, how it is represented in code.

Comment: @JohnColeman I just copied the OP code, I don't know his use case

Comment: @JohnColeman: I see your point, I edited the answer